# HDD 46G used per GParted and df - but only 10G per ncdu, du, baobab etc Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, gparted, disk-usage

Good day. I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running a headless NAS box (HP Microserver) - used mainly for backup, but it also runs Plex Media Server. Plex stopped working and it turned out I was out of disk space. I have cleared out some old kernel versions so have retrieved a little space and Plex is working now. However, I can't identify what is using the extra 36G of space. I would like to clear the space and avoid rebuilding the machine.

`df -h` says 46G used and 98% full (which is consistent with the gparted usage) -

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4        50G   46G  1.4G  98% /
```

but `du -xhs` says  9.5G used -

```
sudo du -xhs /
9.5G    /
```

ncdu and disk usage analyzer (baobab) also show 9.5GB - so they don't show what is using the space (/mnt and /media excluded as they are where my backups are mounted and are TB's in size)

`sudo ncdu --exclude /mnt --exclude /media  /
    1.9GiB [##        ] /usr
    1.1GiB [#         ] /home
  447.6MiB [          ] /lib
   75.9MiB [          ] /boot
    9.5MiB [          ] /sbin
    9.0MiB [          ] /etc
    8.8MiB [          ] /bin
    4.0MiB [          ] /run
  104.0KiB [          ] /root
   36.0KiB [          ] /tmp
e  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
    4.0KiB [          ] /dev
    4.0KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0KiB [          ] /selinux
e   4.0KiB [          ] /opt
e   4.0KiB [          ] /cdrom
.   0.0  B [          ] /proc
    0.0  B [          ] /sys
@   0.0  B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0  B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
<   0.0  B [          ] /mnt
<   0.0  B [          ] /media`

It doesn't seem to be due to open deleted files as `sudo lsof | grep deleted` shows -

```
init          1       root    8w      REG                8,4       500     148491 /var/log/upstart/dbus.log.1 (deleted)
init          1       root   10w      REG                8,4     55813     130877    /var/log/upstart/plexmediaserver.log.1 (deleted)
init          1       root   16w      REG                8,4      4216     133683 /var/log/upstart/modemmanager.log.1 (deleted)
python     9313       plex    8u      REG                8,4      4096    1700647 /tmp/ffifxF1zy (deleted)
```

According `sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +10000c -ls | sort -nrk 7,7 | head` the largest files are listed as -

```
785629 922356 -rw-r--r--   1 plex     plex     944477783 Jul 31 23:47 /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Cache/Transcode/Sync/2428339/2831927/bd789647083c9472caf0.mp4
1346177 850528 -rw-r--r--   1 plex     plex     870935793 May  4 03:20 /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Metadata/TV\ Shows/b/aeae4285550087f5d22a9030c7d5d69a7196b87.bundle/Contents/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia/posters/8e453437ed057792cf502dfb3e43821df94d3b3a
1056823 850528 -rw-r--r--   1 plex     plex 870935793 May  4 03:20 /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Metadata/TV\ Shows/b/aeae4285550087f5d22a9030c7d5d69a7196b87.bundle/Contents/_stored/posters/com.plexapp.agents.localmedia_8e453437ed057792cf502dfb3e43821df94d3b3a
132188 313416 -rw-r--r--   1 plex     plex     320929896 Aug  2 10:36 /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application\ Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Logs/Plex\ Media\ Server.log
398237 254660 -rw-r--r--   1 ben      ben      260765696 Jul 31 23:06 /home/ben/.dropbox/instance1/filecache.dbx
392538 30672 -rw-------   1 ben      ben      252788736 May  9 21:59 /home/ben/core
141515 194704 -rw-r-----   1 syslog   adm      199372800 Jul 27 08:04 /var/log/mail.log.1
141514 189032 -rw-r-----   1 syslog   adm      193562231 Aug  2 10:40 /var/log/mail.log
141340 135192 -rw-r-----   1 syslog   adm      138432512 Jul 27 08:04 /var/log/mail.err.1
140800 132400 -rw-r-----   1 syslog   adm      135570264 Aug  2 10:40 /var/log/mail.err
```

Rebooting makes no difference - I have done so a number of times.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You might try an iterative process using a terminal window starting at the root "/" directory such as the following:

1. In a terminal run `du -sk *`
2. Locate the directory using lots of space, and change into that directory
3. Repeat step 1 until you find the file(s) using all the space, or run out of subdirectories and then need to go back up to the root "/" directory and select the next largest space usage directory.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately du doesn't show what could be taking up the extra 36G of space. Output below - `root@HP:/# du -skh *
8.9M    bin
76M     boot
4.0K    cdrom
4.0K    dev
9.1M    etc
1.2G    home
0       initrd.img.old
448M    lib
4.0K    lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
4.7T    mnt
4.0K    opt
0       proc
104K    root
4.1M    run
9.5M    sbin
4.0K    selinux
4.0K    srv
0       sys
36K     tmp
1.9G    usr
6.6G    var
0       vmlinuz.old`