# How can I find the files that Filelight isn't showing? DiskFree shows 227GB used; Filelight shows only 89GB used

Tags: disk-usage, trash

Ubuntu 20.04, with KDE installed on top.

I'm running low on space on my root drive. Which isn't that big of a deal because I can always just move things to the other drives on my system.

Normally, I'd use a tool like Dirstat or Filelight to show me where the biggest space hogs are, so I can easily and effectively free up space. *But* Dirstat always crashes on launch for me, so it's useless. And Filelight apparently isn't showing some files.

Filelight says I'm only using 89GB on the 256GB drive, which would be great. *But* Dolphin and DiskFree both show that I'm using 227GB of it, with only 2.6GB of free space! So, either *both* of those are wrong, or -- more likely -- there's something taking up 138GB on the drive that Filelight isn't able to detect for some reason.

I've already tried the `trash-empty` command, and that hasn't helped matters, so it doesn't seem to be the trash directory that's hogging space. Unless there's some other, better trash cleanup command I should use.

I've also tried `du -h --max-depth=2` and its results seem to agree with Filelight, even when run as root. Meanwhile, `df /` shows the disk as 99% used, agreeing with Dolphin and DiskFree.

Tried running `sudo filelight` and it *did* find more files, but it says there's 91GB used ... a far cry from the 227GB that's apparently being used.

So my questions are:

A) Is there a better program I could use to show disk usage by directory and more easily find the space wasters? Or is there maybe some way to get Filelight to see the files it's missing?

B) Does anyone know what phantom files might be using this space and how to move or delete them?

[image]

[image]

Relevant portion of `lsblk`:

```
nvme2n1     259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme2n1p1 259:3    0   512M  0 part 
└─nvme2n1p2 259:4    0 232.4G  0 part /
```

`sudo lsof |& grep deleted -c` outputs only: `41130` ... which doesn't seem particularly informative. It doesn't seem to represent any of the running processes on my system. (I ran `ps aux` and none of the processes listed have an id of "41130".) Unless that means there are 41130 deleted files still open somewhere and taking up space?

Edit: this seems very similar to a much older question:
[HDD 46G used per GParted and df - but only 10G per ncdu, du, baobab etc Ubuntu 12.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505669/hdd-46g-used-per-gparted-and-df-but-only-10g-per-ncdu-du-baobab-etc-ubuntu-1?rq=1)
But, unfortunately, that one also remains unsolved.

Tried `sudo boabab` and got some weird results.
The summary screen says 244GB used:
[image]
But when I click on it to see the details, it only finds 94GB of files:
[image]

Comment: Add the output of `lsblk` and `sudo lsof |& grep deleted -c` to the post, please. (Paste the output as text, using code formatting, instead of as a screenshot)

Comment: @muru -- done, though I'm afraid it didn't seem to add much useful information.

Comment: Please add the full output. The 41130 indicates you have 41130 *deleted* files still being used by processes in your system, so those might be taking up space as well.

Comment: That *is* the full output. It gave me only that number and nothing else at all.

Comment: I meant for `lsblk` - so that we can see what is mounted where and might be masking some disk usage. The `lsof | grep` command was meant to output just that number - the number of deleted files. You can remove the `-c` at the end to see which deleted files are in use, but with 41130 entries I don't think showing us the complete output of that is going to be useful. You can examine that yourself to see if there's something deleted taking up a lot of space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that still-open deleted files *were* taking up free space. Thanks to @muru for leading me toward that conclusion.

Weird that there would be over 100GB of that, but I was able to clear up *some* space (about 2GB) by force-closing and restarting a few applications.

I suspect that the rest of it will be freed up the next time I do a cold reboot, though that won't be for a while yet because I don't want to interrupt things already in progress.